# Java distributed tasks

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I am building system which should be consisted of 3 servers and same Java (Spring mvc) service would be running on all 3 of them. 
Service will be able to do 3 categories of tasks, i.e. A, B and C.

What I want is to make each service on servers perform only one category while communicating with other server. If one server dies, remaining servers should negotiate and only one of them should take category.

Example:

1. Server 1 - Service does A

   Server 2 - Service does B

   Server 3 - Service does C
2. Server 2 Dies

   Server 1 and Server 3 negotiate

   Server 1 - Service does A and B

   Server 3 - Service does C

If server 2 returns to normal state it should take category from Server 1 (A or B)

Is there any pattern, architecture, technology, link that could help me solve this?

Comment: This question would be better asked on site like http://serverfault.com/. StackOverflow is about asking questions about programming and not general architecture questions.

Comment: You could simplify it a whole lot by just letting all servers do all tasks. Then use a message queue like RabbitMQ or Amazon SQS or something to hand out the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

`Zookeeper` was especially meant for handling these types of scenarios in distributed environment. One master will be elected out of N number of servers by acquiring a lock. Once master dies, it causes re-election and new master will serve client requests.

Other alternative,which is error prone is implementing  a shared global distributed lock by yourself and handle corner cases. The server who acquires the lock will serve the client requests.

From [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) documentation page:

> ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services. All of these kinds of services are used in some form or another by distributed applications

[image]

You can find more details in [zookeeper Overview](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperOver.html) page.